# adding a number to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add a number to an array in JS, but only if the number is a multiple of three. Here's my code:

```
var numbers = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    if i % 3 === 0 {    
        numbers.push(i);            
    }
}
alert(numbers);
```

But the code does not print anything. It works fine without the if statement though, when I just add the numbers between 1 and 200...

Can you find the error?

Thanks!

Comment: This: `if i % 3 === 0` You have to wrap the condition in parenthesis.

Comment: What does the error console say?

Comment: have you looked at the console output? it should become pretty clear what's going on.

Comment: @varnie She just took a look at SO console ...

Comment: I don't see this question as useful as it's caused by a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick fix is `if (i % 3 === 0) {`

But why don't you write `for (i = 3; i <= 200; i += 3)` instead and remove the modulus check?

Answer (score 4):

You need some brackets for the if statement.

```js
var numbers = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {    
    // ^           ^
        numbers.push(i);            
    }
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var numbers = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 200;i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {    // () execution brackets necessary
            numbers.push(i);            
        }
    }

    // better way to do
    var numbers = [];
    var i = 3; // better to declare it here
    for (; i <= 200; i += 3) {
        //  if (i % 3 == 0) {    not required as Bathsheba's answer
            numbers.push(i);            
        //  }
    }
```